# I want to make a separate domain for images

Tags: virtualhost, apache

I want to set up a domain called img.mydomain.com. It will be a virtual domain that just like my actual domain except for one difference: it will only serve files that end in .jpg .jpeg .gif .png etc.  This way I can refer to img.mydomain.com/some_image.jpg. it will speed up the page speed by making the browser think that it's two separate domains (google page speed analyzer is always nagging me to do this).

I'm running apache on a linux server. Should I do this in httpd.conf? If so, what is my first step?

Comment: What web-server are you using? Apache?

Answer (score 6):

create 2 folder for each domains (for example):

- /var/www/domain.com
- /var/www/img.domain.com/

here's what you can put in your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain.com"
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
  <Directory "/var/www/domain.com">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/img.domain.com/"
  ServerName img.domain.com
  ServerAlias img.domain.com
  <Directory "/var/www/img.domain.com/">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```