# very simple -- how do i setup a subdomain with 1&1 domain provider + hostgator hosting?

Tags: dns, hosting, subdomain

Everytime I try to create a subdomain with this combo, it simply says the page doesn't exist.  I have the subdomain directory created, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  for example if I want 
`subdomain.domain.com`, then
`domain.com/subdomain` will work, but
`subdomain.domain.com` won't work.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you will need a DNS record for you subdomain. This can be a CNAME record if you just want the the subdomain to be an alias of the main domain (Canonical Name). If you want the subdomain to be hosted on a different IP address or server then you need a new A record.

From the sounds of it you want a CNAME record for your subdomain created in your DNS manager, and then you want to configure your web server to look at the host headers to map to the sub directory you created. How you go about this depends on the type of web server.

Comment: If you are using Apache then the following is likely to help: [Apache Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896548/i-want-to-make-a-separate-domain-for-images)

Comment: thanks man, you really cleared that up.  I was having trouble differentiating between the lingo: DNS, CNAME and A-record

Comment: @Brad_R 

EFFFFFFFFFF Yes, thank you so much man.  I just solved something that has been bugging the absolute crap out of me for so long.  I owe you 1 and a half man.  Thanks again :)))